# Narrow a list of items as you type with javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms, plugins, autocomplete

I am trying to find a plugin or a solid way to narrow a list of items as a user types.

Essentially there would be a list that is always visible containing product names for users to scroll through. At the bottom would be a form where you can type in the name of a product. As you type the list is narrowed down.

I have been trying to find a way to adapt something like jQuery UI's autocomplete to work in this way but having some trouble.

Anyone created something like this before or have any ideas?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Here's a quick example of an approach that can work:

HTML:

```
<ul id="products">
    <li>Apple</li>
    <li>Banana</li>
    <li>Mango</li>
</ul>
<input id="filter" />
```

jQuery:

```
var $products = $('#products li');
$('#filter').keyup(function() {
    var re = new RegExp($(this).val(), "i"); // "i" means it's case-insensitive
    $products.show().filter(function() {
        return !re.test($(this).text());
    }).hide();
});
```

That's a simple approach and would probably need a bit of tweaking, but it's close to what you need.

Answer (score 5):

How about the [quickSearch](https://github.com/riklomas/quicksearch) plugin?